# Set Max Increment jQuery

Tags: jquery, max

I am using buttons to increment a control that shows the count of tabs. The maximum limit for #clickedTab needs to be 6.

Decreasing works fine and stops at 1. incrementing should stop at 6.

I am using below code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  //ARROW CONTROLS
  $("#prevtab").click(function() {
    $('#clickedTab').html(function(i, val) {
      return val * 1 <= 1 ? 1 : val * 1 - 1
    });
  });
  $("#nexttab").click(function() {
    $('#clickedTab').html(function(i, val) {
      return val * 1 + 1
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#clickedTab { display:inline }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control">
  <button id="prevtab" class="prevtab">prev</button>
  <span class="numbers dark md_font bold control-wrap"><div id="clickedTab">1</div>/6</span>
  <button id="nexttab" class="nexttab">next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you multiplying by 1? If you want to convert a string to a number, the usual idiom is `+val`

Comment: So you need the same logic you have in the other one!!!

Comment: `return val * 1 + 1` there's no attempt here to limit it to 6.   Your `prev` button limits to `1` so just use the same code but `=>6` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

val < 6 ? val * 1 + 1 : val

If val lower then 6 then val * 1 + 1 else just val.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  //ARROW CONTROLS
  $("#prevtab").click(function() {
    $('#clickedTab').html(function(i, val) {
      return val * 1 <= 1 ? 1 : val * 1 - 1
    });
  });
  $("#nexttab").click(function() {
    $('#clickedTab').html(function(i, val) {
      return val < 6 ? val * 1 + 1 : val
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control">
  <button id="prevtab" class="prevtab">-</button>
  <span class="numbers dark md_font bold control-wrap"><div id="clickedTab">1</div>/6</span>
  <button id="nexttab" class="nexttab">+</button>
</div>
```